# How to make tabs change information when swiping left/right (from empty activity)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

In Android Studio I want to have a different tab every time I swipe left/right. So I want to make information on a 'page' change when I swipe left/right, with the animation of moving in that direction. I do not know how to use fragments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update the List whenever the tabs are changing in view pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231180/how-to-update-the-list-whenever-the-tabs-are-changing-in-view-pager)

Answer (score 0):

you want to get position of fragments if it swap so you need to add page change listener.

```
 viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // it returns position 
//do there your code according position

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think youre looking for this one
[View Pager with Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413437/5868103)
and [Creating Swipe Views with Tabs Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) Tutorials for [ActionBar Tabs with Fragments.](https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

Comment: Don't put comments in answer post. gave description of your answer otherwise post in comments.