# Listview in android tabbed layout

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have implemented a `TabLayout` in android with two fragments. In one fragment I added a `ListView`. I am retrieving data from server to fill up the `ListView`. Everything was working fine until I tried to access the `ListView` from the `MainActivity` class.

I need access of the same listview(which is in the fragment) from the MainActivity where I created the `TabLayout` to load data. The fragment is created for a tab of the tablayout.

I added the code below.

Can anyone tell me how can I access that `ListView` from the `MainActivity`?
**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detailed_report);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

**ReportListFragment.java**

```
public class ReportListFragment extends Fragment{



private SimpleDateFormat mFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy hh:mm aa");
Date newDate;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);
    finder_sharedprefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(FINDERPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    listView=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    reportLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.new_report);




        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: do you want send data to the mainactivity that contains the fragments ? correct ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan No. I have added the listview in the fragment layout. But now I need to access it from the activity class.

Comment: so you want something like this. When you click some button in your activity, add 1 row to the listview inside the fragment that is wrapped in the same activity ? correct >

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan yes almost right. I want to reload data after clicking a button on the activity.

Comment: You can refer -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/18611036/3817374

Comment: @codehub does the link helps you ?

Comment: check my answer if it helps you @codehub

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check this answer if it helps you,

In your respective Fragment code create a public function

**FragmentA.java**
create a function like below.

```
    public void getData(int r) {
        Log.e("data got from Activity", "" + r); // this is sample
        //Do your updations to list view here.
      }
```

Now in your **mainActivity.java** call this function like below wherever you want

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        new FragmentA().getData(34);
      }
    });
```

Now check the log cat. you will see the number 34 is printed. 
Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: please see my codes. May be my question is not clear to you. I want to access the ListView from a fragment class to an Activity class. Is that possible? If not, I will try something else.

Comment: you want the listview inside the fragment to be updated when you click button in the activity ? correct ?