# How to determine a fragment in FragmentStatePagerAdapter is current page or not

Tags: android, android-fragments

FragmentStatePagerAdapter(for short FSPA) has pre-load mechanism.

We assume that A,B and C Fragment in FSPA

When user select the A Fragment, the B fragment will be pre-load, something in B fragment don't want to be executed because B is not the current fragment.

How cloud i determine if a fragment is a current fragment user selected ?

> The code snippet can't explain what i want to do, so i have deleted it

Update my question as below :

Assume that

1. there are three fragments  A , B, C in viewPager
2. fragment A is the first visible to user.
3. start e-ticket transaction if fragment A is visible to user
4. In other page (except fragment A), we need to stop e-ticket transaction

**Problem:**
Pre-load fragment A in viewpager will cause that user don't see a e-ticket present but e-ticket start transaction

**Want to do:**
View of fragment A is a e-ticket, so transaction can be started in fragment A only and stop in other fragment.

p.s. start and stop e-ticket transaction are in A fragment class.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609261/getting-the-current-fragment-instance-in-the-viewpager). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `onPageChangeListener` to your viewpager and inside `onPageSelected(int position)` you can get the current fragment as.

```
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
             Fragment currentFragment=new MyViewPagerAdapter().getItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Ps- By 'user select' do you mean Clicked or Visible on screen?

Comment: It seems that i have to pass viewPager reference to fragment...

Because i have to do something in fragment only

Comment: inside from a fragment as you are doing in 'onResume()' try 'if(fragmentObject.isVisible()){//Do something}

Comment: Ps- By 'user select' do you mean Clicked or Visible on screen? Yes,

Comment: did you try this... if(fragmentObject.isVisible())
{
//Do something
}

Comment: It's not work for me...After onCreateView(), isVisible() always return true in onResume, so it's can't determine the fragment is clicked or not

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do after user clicks on the fragment?

Comment: Finally, i adopt your suggestion to modify my code to finish the requirement, thanks

Comment: You can accept the answer then, that will help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setUserVisibleHint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)) method.

```
 @Override
        public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
if(isVisibleToUser){
... your code
}
    }
```

Comment: The method to be called before onCreateView, but i need to do something after view is ready, if a task is independent of views, it could be a good idea.