# FloatingActionButton appearing under screen when using TabLayout and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

Take a look at the `FAB` below:

[image]

It's not appearing unless I collapse the `Toolbar`. Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layoutDirection="locale"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/cLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/accent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/list"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Why is this happening if I set no behavior for the `FAB`? Is there any property I should add to anything so I could prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Remove this line from the top relative layout `android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"`

Comment: And make the coordinator layout as the top most layout

Comment: @cafebabe1991 didn't work

Comment: had the exact same problem once, provide your entire layout code. without it solving this problem isn't going to be any feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove your `FloatingActionButton` from each `Fragment` and add it to your `Activity`.  This way not only the FAB stays in place but it also fixes your problem. Then you can use `getActivity().findViewByIf(id)` in your `Fragment` and set an `onClickListener` in each `Fragment`.

Comment: The problem with the click event. How to find which fragment currently visible ?

Comment: You can try this approaches.
1.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609261/getting-the-current-fragment-instance-in-the-viewpager
2.https://pupli.net/2017/06/05/get-current-fragment-displayed-in-viewpager-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove your RelativeLayout and restructure your layout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/cLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/accent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/list"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
<com.rey.material.widget.ProgressView
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    app:pv_autostart="true"
    app:pv_circular="true"
    app:pv_progressMode="indeterminate"
    app:pv_progressStyle="@style/Material.Drawable.CircularProgress" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Coordinator layout does not behave like relative layout, you can not have multiple children without disturbing each other. so just make one child of coordinator layout i.e relative layout and inside it add recyclerView and floatingActionButton

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

          <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
              android:id="@+id/list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/accent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
                    app:layout_anchor="@id/list"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" /></RelativeLayout>
```