# Get Fragment from ViewPager Android

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my MainActivity I have Transaction my MainFragment.

```
MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_holder, mainFragment)
            .addToBackStack(mainFragment.getClass().getName())
            .commit();
```

at my MainFragment I'm using a ViewPager together with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter to host My fragment.

```
public class TaskPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private String cookieString = null;

private String userString = null;

public TaskPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Cookie cookie) {
    super(fm);
    this.cookieString = HttpUtil.serializeCookie(cookie);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new NotificationFragment();
            break;
//            case 1:
//                break;
//            case 2:
//                break;
//            case 3:
//                break;
//            case 4:
//                break;

    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return new String[]{"رویدادها", "توضیحات", "فرم ها"}[position];
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
}
```

and in my MainFragment:

```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
   ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
        mPagerAdapter = new TaskPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),cookie);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
  return rootView;
```

according this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609261/getting-the-current-fragment-instance-in-the-viewpager) I write this commend into main fragment:

```
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);


    Fragment page = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" +
            R.id.pager + ":" + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
    NotificationFragment fragment = (NotificationFragment) page;
    fragment.setNotificationCallBack(this);


    mCountNotifyTask.getCountNotifyTask();
    return rootView;
```

**but page retrieve null**!! what is you suggestion?
I am using [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter#setup-smartfragmentstatepageradapter)

I still got null.

```
NotificationFragment fragment = (NotificationFragment) mPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using activities fragment manager, use ChildFragmentManager in your MainFragment

```
 mPagerAdapter = new TaskPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),cookie);
 mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
 mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

And to get the fragment use the child fragment manager

```
Fragment page = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" +
        R.id.pager + ":" + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
NotificationFragment fragment = (NotificationFragment) page;
```

**Remember:** ViewPager adds and removes fragment based on its current position
I would suggest to keep all the fragment instance in the adapter as an ArrayList and retrive them when you need it based on the position index

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: can you send me a link as an example?

Comment: one fragment for now but after i want to put 4 fragments.

Comment: but I have to put bundle to each fragment:         `Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(MainFragment.ARG_COOKIE, cookieString);
        fragment.setArguments(args);return fragment;` in getItem()

Comment: You can do this within the MainFragment and pass that to the adapter.