# RecyclerView inside PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android

I have a main fragment that contains a viewpager. This viewpager gets the same secondary fragment (different from the main one) but with different parameters every time. Inside the said secondary fragment that is inside the viewpager, i have a recyclerview. Inside these recyclerviews are some fields that the user fills up. When the main fragment (the one that holds the viewpager) is closed (via a button click) i need to get the data from each recyclerview. How do i to that?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is that implement interface which will give call back to activity holding these fragment and then from Activity pass it to fragment(main) and then use viewpager to get Fragment(secondry) and pass data.

Steps one would be implent interface which will give callback to activity and the get fragment from viewpager([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18609926/1591934) for same)