# How to show Admob Interstitial ad after 5 swipes in vertical viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, admob, android-adapter, interstitial

I have made an app in which I have added functionality of vertical swipe using ViewPager class. Now I need help to show Admob Interstitial ad after 5 swipes. I have seen several other SO question but could not get clarity.

Can anyone help me how can I do this? Here is my code:

MainActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mains);  

        mData = dbHelper.getAll(Data.class);
        DATA_CARDS = mData.size();

        ScreenSlidePagerAdapter screenSlidePagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        VerticalViewPager verticalViewPager = (VerticalViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        verticalViewPager.setAdapter(screenSlidePagerAdapter);      
    }
```

ScreenSlidePagerAdapter

```
public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private static final int NUM_PAGES = MainActivity.DATA_CARDS;

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        SlidingFragment slidingFragment = new SlidingFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("position", position);
        slidingFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return slidingFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

VerticalViewPager

```
    public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());]
        setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    }

    private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

        @Override
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

            if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                view.setAlpha(0);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
                view.setAlpha(1);

                // Counteract the default slide transition
                view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

                //set Y position to swipe in from top
                float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
                view.setTranslationY(yPosition);

            } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                view.setAlpha(0);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
     */
    private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
        float width = getWidth();
        float height = getHeight();

        float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
        float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

        ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

        return ev;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
        swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
        return intercepted;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `PageChangeListener` to the view pager and counting the `onPageSelected calls?`

Comment: @insa_c No, How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `PageChangeListener` to your view pager and call the `onPageSelected()` calls, for this you need to have class field called e.g. `int mAdCounter = 0`:

```
verticalViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mAdCount++;
            if (mAdCount % 5 == 0) {
            //Display your add
            //It's better if you load the ad before you need to display it, you can hide the adview and load it
            } else {
            //Hide the adView
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: after showing an ad in `onPageSelected` I can swipe the add also as I am doing currently with my fragments?

Comment: create an abstract base fragment class and create a abstract function like `showAds(boolean shouldDisplay)` , and you can get the current fragment from view pager:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18611036/5152910)
then cast the fragment to the base fragment and call the `showAds()` on that fragment to display or remove the ad. Although I would recommend you to have the ad on the activity. not on the fragment

Comment: cureently I am swapping fragments vertically n viewpager, now i want to show ad after 5 swipes and I can swipe ad too as I am swapping fragment.