# Scroll RecyclerView that is within FragmentStatePageAdaptor

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that is within a Fragment that extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter.  I want to scroll the recyclerView when i click a button of some sort.  The problem is that using `mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(selectedPosition)` is scrolling the next fragment.  Is there a way to capture the current fragment and perform the scroll operation on the it? All the answers I found involve fragments that extend `FragmentPagerAdapter`.  I can't use this fragment because, my app has more than a 1000 fragments, which should be loaded on the case by case bases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of serching i was able to find a great answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42206176/7504259). With in my app clicking a button scrolls the recyclerview to the desired position.

```
int pagePosition = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
MyAdaptor adaptor = (MyAdaptor) mViewPager.getAdapter();
RecyclerView recyclerView = ((MyFragment) adaptor.instantiateItem(mViewPager, pagePosition)).mRecyclerView;
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, null, mScrollToPosition);
```