# Fragment View is null when try to access from Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I have created a Fragment which is in ViewPager. Fragment is loading fine. 
I am using a button to swipe fragments in viewpager and before swiping, I want to check validations. So I did this in Activity :

```
val pos: Int = viewPager.currentItem
            val activeFragment: Fragment? = mAdapter.getItem(pos)
            if (viewPager.currentItem == 0) {

                if (pos == 0) (activeFragment as FragmentOne).checkValidation()
```

Below is my Fragment code.

```
class FragmentOne: BaseFragment() {

        fun newInstance(): FragmentOne{
            val args = Bundle()
            val fragment = FragmentOne()
            fragment.setArguments(args)
            return fragment
        }


        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                                  savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val view : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
            return view
        }

        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        }

        override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
            initiateUI()
        }


        fun checkValidation(): Boolean {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etDateOfBirth.text.toString())) {
                showMessage(etDateOfBirth, getString(R.string.str_empty_dob))
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
    }
```

When I press next I get error:
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: etDateOfBirth must not be null**
Can anyone help out?

Comment: Because `getItem` returns a NEW instance of the Fragment which is not added to your Activity and has no inflated layout.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce what should I do to achieve my flow...?? Any workaround for it?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce how will that work?? instantiateItem is deprecated and it does not return fragment.? Can you tell me how to use that.? Or give some reference may be

Comment: Okay. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609261/getting-the-current-fragment-instance-in-the-viewpager

Comment: As EpicpandaForce already mentioned you can't simply call getItem(pos) because that would give you a **new** Fragment  each time you call it. Instead you should use something like this https://gist.github.com/luksprog/183c31ca77dba4be8c9e891db24c2fae

Answer (score 2):

Didn't you define etDateOfBirth? Define edit text on onViewCreated()

```
EditText etDateOfBirth = view.findViewById(R.id.sample);
```