# ExoPlayer shows wrong preview image while swiping screens through ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a `PlayerView` that takes up the top half of the Fragment in portrait orientation with the bottom half showing some text. The fragment is a part of a `ViewPager` and a user can switch screens with different videos.

**Problem:** While navigating between screens (swiping right/left) the `PlayerView` sometimes shows a preview image from the previous screen. It is shown just for a fraction of a second and then it shows the correct preview picture, but it is noticeable.

**Question:** How do I make the `PlayerView` show only the correct preview picture? It shouldn't blink with the previous picture. May be I'm misusing something (wrong instantiation of the Player or the View...)? May be some workaround if it is a known issue(blurring the video while swiping, etc)? Any suggestion/idea is appreciated.

Here is **how my layout looks like**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/video_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Fragment code I have:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    ...
    SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
            getActivity(), new DefaultTrackSelector()
    );
    player.prepare(mediaSource);
    playerView.setPlayer(player);
    ...
}
```

**EDIT 1.**

As requested in the comments section my `PageAdapter` is pretty standard (just like the one Android Studio generates while creating a Tabbed Activity) with the only extension - I save current fragment in it [just like it is suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21104114/2065796).

Comment: Just a guess: your fragment might restore from previous state to show old preview, and then show the correct video after it is loaded. However, difficult to say something definite without seeing the code of `PagerAdapter`.

Comment: Is `savedInstanceState` null in `onCreate()` of the Fragment?

Comment: @atarasenko `savedInstanceState` is null when the fragment gets created for the first time. But when the issue happens it doesn't even enter `onCreate()` method. Please take a look on my edit regarding `PagerAdapter` and feel free to ask if something else needed.

Comment: same issue with me have you found any solution

Comment: @kishanverma no, I have not.

Comment: @SashaShpota i found somthing

Comment: @kishanverma I am facing a similar issue in viewpager can so share the solution if you have solved the issue.