# Unable to edit ActionBar title from Fragment in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a single `Activity` which hosts multiple fragments through a `ViewPager`. In the Activity's `onCreate` method I'm using the following code to change the `ActionBar` title:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.custom_title));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

It works fine, but then I am unable to change it as soon as a `Fragment` becomes visible. In order to detect it I've implemented:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {

    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser && getContext() != null) {
            ((MainActivity) getContext()).editActionBarTitle("new title");
    }
}
```

And here's the definition for `editActionBarTitle`:

```
public void editActionBarTitle(String title) {
     if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
         getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     }
}
```

I can see that the method gets called as soon as a fragment becomes visible, but it has no effect on the ActionBar's title. What am I missing in order to edit the title correctly?

---

**EDIT**

I've also tried implementing `addOnPageChangeListener` in the `viewPager`, I can see that the method `onPageSelected` gets called but it has no effect on the title, here's an example on MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {   

    private NoScrollViewPager mViewPager;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Toolbar initialization
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MainActivity");
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        // ViewPager initialization
        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.containter);
        setupViewPager();
    }

    private void setupViewPager() {

        mAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "Fragment 1");
        mAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "Fragment 2");
        mAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment3(), "Fragment 3");

        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mAdapter.getCount());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // viewPager event listener
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) { }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                setTitle("fragment " + position);
                if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("fragment " + position);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { }
        });
    }

    public void setViewPager(int position) { mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position); }
}
```

This is the custom `ViewPager` class:

```
public class NoScrollViewPager extends ViewPager {

    // Disable horizontal scrolling in ViewPager
    private boolean isPagingEnabled = false;

    public NoScrollViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NoScrollViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressLint("AndroidLintClickableViewAccessibility")
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
        this.isPagingEnabled = b;
    }
}
```

And this is the custom Adapter class:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        fragmentManager = fm;
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) { return mFragmentList.get(position); }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return mFragmentList.size(); }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) { return POSITION_NONE; }

}
```

Comment: Try this `((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle();`

Answer (score 7):

Try this in your onCreateView method into fragment. May be it will helps you.

```
if(getActivity() != null){
     getActivity().setTitle("Your title");
}
```

If you used ViewPager inside a fragment then you can use

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisible) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisible);

        if (isVisible) {
            if(getActivity() != null){
               getActivity().setTitle("Your title");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't use it inside `onCreateView` because each fragment is loaded inside a `ViewPager` so that method is called as soon as I instantiate the ViewPager. That's why I'm using `setUserVisibleHint` to detect when one of the fragment becomes visible.

Comment: Just use the code above inside your `setUserVisibleHint` and it should work.

Comment: Yes, if you used ViewPager then you can use setUserVisibleHint to detect when the fragment becomes visible.

Comment: Thanks to @LS_ Now, I am added this to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [**`viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener))

- Add a listener that will be invoked whenever the page changes or is incrementally scrolled

In `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener()` you need to set title in your `actionbar` inside **`onPageSelected()`**

which returns the current the current selected page in  `viewpager`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {

            if (i == 0) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment One");
            } else if (i == 1) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment Two");
            } else if (i == 2) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment three");
            } else if (i == 3) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment four");
            } else if (i == 4) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment Five");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });
```

here is the working code for me

> activity code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;


public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private NoScrollViewPager mViewPager;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // Toolbar initialization
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment One");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // ViewPager initialization
        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.containter);

        findViewById(R.id.btnOne).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.btnTwo).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.btnThree).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            }
        });

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {

                if (i == 0) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment One");
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment Two");
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment three");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });


        setupViewPager();


    }

    private void setupViewPager() {

        mAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "Fragment 1");
        mAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "Fragment 2");
        mAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment3(), "Fragment 3");

        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mAdapter.getCount());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // viewPager event listener
    }


}
```

> Layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Frag 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Frag 2" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnThree"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Frag 3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <neel.com.demo.NoScrollViewPager
        android:id="@+id/containter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytJogOkj1zQ

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that I've already tried using `addOnPageChangeListener` but still the title doesn't change. I've added a code example of how I initialize the viewPager and the adapter

Comment: @LS_ can u share your whole activity  code or if possible share your code in github

Comment: I've added an example of the Activity with only the relevant code and the custom classes for the ViewPager and the Adapter

Comment: @LS_ for me your code is working fine can u share where you are changing the viewpager item

Comment: I've added the definition of an helper method `setViewPager` in `MainActivity` which just sets the specified item in the viewPager. I call this method from the fragments (eg. inside an onClickListener). From the fragment I call the method like: `((MainActivity) getContext()).setViewPager(0);` (ps. Thanks for the help!)

Comment: @LS_ have u tried my updated answer and also check the output video that i have added in my answer

Comment: Yes I've tried but still it doesn't have any effect, the title remains the same. It makes me think it's just a simple issue which I just haven't spot yet, will try again later and I'll let you know. Thanks again

Comment: @LS_  can u share the code of your `BaseActivity` may be issue with that

Comment: Still haven't found a solution :( My `BaseActivity` is empty, it just extends `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: @LS_ test case create a demo project and add your code in new project and check it work or not

Comment: Yes gonna try that, btw I'll assign you the bounty since this is the most complete answer to me, I'm still not sure what my issue could be but I'll keep the post updated if I find a solution.

Comment: @LS_ thanks and let me know the result of that and if you required any help just ping me

Comment: Sure! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The only legitimate way of understanding, that `FragmentA` is getting displayed in `ViewPager` is reacting to [`OnPageChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener) callbacks.

Adopting the technique mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18609926/1083957) you could end up having following code:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(final int i) {
            MyAdapter adapter = ((MyAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter());
            TitleOwner titleOwner = adapter.getTitleOwner(index);
            String title = titleOwner.getTitle();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int i) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(final int i,final float v,final int i1) {
        }
});
```

This assumes, that all of the fragments, that are displayed in `ViewPager`, implement `TitleOwner`:

```
interface TitleOwner {
    String getTitle();
}
```

And fragment classes:

```
class MainScreenFragment extends Fragment implements TitleOwner {
    ...
    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return "Main Screen";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if you are using a `NoActionBar` theme. For example `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` or `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in one of my recent project. I ended up designing individual Toolbar for each of the fragments having its own Title. I did use:

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in onPageSelected from

```
setTitle("fragment " + position);
if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("fragment " + position);
}
```

to this

```
toolbar.setTitle(title);
```

and extend AppCompatActivity instead of BaseActivity.
Keep the same code in onCreate