# Get current fragment with ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager, androidx

I'm migrating my `ViewPager` to `ViewPager2` since the latter is supposed to solve all the problems of the former. Unfortunately, when using it with a `FragmentStateAdapter`, I don't find any way to get the currently displayed fragment.

`viewPager.getCurrentItem()` gives the current displayed index and `adapter.getItem(index)` generally creates a new `Fragment` for the current index. Unless keeping a reference to all created fragments in `getItem()`, I have no idea how to access the currently displayed fragment.

With the old `ViewPager`, one solution was to call `adapter.instantiateItem(index)` which would return the fragment at the desired index.

Am I missing something with `ViewPager2`?

Comment: Did you get any solution for your query?

Comment: No, no solution yet.

Comment: `fragmentManager.findFragmentById(getItemId(index).toInt())` from within the `FragmentStateAdapter` seems to work but only after the fragment has been added. 

From the docs this may not work though if the fragments are moved.
`Default implementation works for collections that don't add, move, remove items`

Comment: Just a general note for future readers (I know this isn't your question). If you're looking for a way to notify the fragment that it's been displayed, you can use a ViewModel and have each fragment observe the same ViewModel. Then each fragment would respond if their `javaClass.name` matches what was passed in.

Comment: Working solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/69440532/2064336

Answer (score 113):

In `ViewPager2` the FragmentManager by default have assigned tags to fragments like this:

Fragment in 1st position has a tag of `"f0"`

Fragment in 2nd position has a tag of `"f1"`

Fragment in 3rd position has a tag of `"f2"` and so on... so you can get your fragment's tag and by concatenating the "f" with position of your fragment. To get the current Fragment you can get current position from the viewPager2 position and make your tag like this (For Kotlin):

```
val myFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("f" + viewpager.currentItem)
```

For fragment at a certain position

```
val myFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("f" + position)
```

You can cast the Fragment and always check if it is not null if you are using this technique.

If you host your ViewPager2 in Fragment, use `childFragmentManager` instead.

**REMEMBER**

If you have `overriden` the `getItemId(position: Int)` in your adapter. Then your case is different. It should be:

```
val myFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("f" + your_id_at_that_position)
```

OR SIMPLY:

```
val myFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("f" + adapter.getItemId(position))
```

If you host your ViewPager2 in Fragment, use `childFragmentManager` instead of `supportFragmentManager`.

Comment: Note that if want to use this approach in host Fragment, you have to use `childFragmentManager`.

Comment: You can Edit the answer to add those details @Micer

Comment: Important note is that if you override getItemId() in your adapter, this pattern won't work. Because FragmentStateAdapter uses "f" + holder.getItemId() when adds fragment. By default getItemId returns position, but if you override then it will have different value.

Comment: Or that's great work there I think since you have overriden getItemID you also know the ID of each fragment so the tags will be `"f"+yourID.toString()` @RuslanMyhal

Comment: What if tommorow they decide to change the tag?

Comment: There are other solutions to the problem like preserving the reference to the Fragment etc. But I can not get worried for something with 0.1% chance of occurence. @Dr.aNdRO

Comment: How can you be so sure on this number 0.1%?

Comment: Because there is no need for a change. What might be a reason for that change? Also `ViewPager2` is open source library that is not tied to Android Platform. Basically I don't see any reasons for worrying @Dr. aNdRO

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO 's right though, the internal naming scheme isn't part of the API, so it could change at any time, for any reason, without any warning. It's a solution that works, but it's brittle and you can't rely on it, so if that's important to you you need to be aware of the risks

Comment: What if you have multiple view pagers? I don't like this solution at all

Comment: @Xenolion that is the worst code smell possible, I would't use this in production in any app released to the public.... one night, google decides to change this naming system and you will be fighting google play to approve your update fast.

Comment: No, it does not work like that. The naming convention of the ViewPager will be already on your APK in PlayStore. So there will be no need to change your code unless you change the ViewPager2 library. @RafaelLima

Comment: Indeed, as long as you dont update your dependency and use configurations.all {    resolutionStrategy.force "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"   } to prevent other libs from implicitly upgrading it, this will not break.

Answer (score 25):

The solution to find current Fragment by its tag seems the most suitable for me. I've created these extension functions for that:

```
fun ViewPager2.findCurrentFragment(fragmentManager: FragmentManager): Fragment? {
    return fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("f$currentItem")
}

fun ViewPager2.findFragmentAtPosition(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    position: Int
): Fragment? {
    return fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("f$position")
}
```

- If your ViewPager2 host is `Activity`, use `supportFragmentManager`
  or `fragmentManager`.
- If your ViewPager2 host is `Fragment`, use `childFragmentManager`

Note that:

- `findFragmentAtPosition` will work only for Fragments that were initialized in ViewPager2's RecyclerView. Therefore you can get only the positions that are visible + 1.
- Lint will suggest you to remove `ViewPager2.` from `fun ViewPager2.findFragmentAtPosition`, because you don't use anything from ViewPager2 class. I think it should stay there, because this workaround applies solely to ViewPager2.

Answer (score 19):

I had similar problem when migrating to `ViewPager2`.

In my case I decided to use `parentFragment` property (I think you can make it also work for activity) and hope, that `ViewPager2` will keep only the current fragment resumed. (i.e. page fragment that was resumed last is the current one.)

So in my main fragment (`HostFragment`) that contains `ViewPager2` view I created following property:

```
private var _currentPage: WeakReference<MyPageFragment>? = null
val currentPage
    get() = _currentPage?.get()

fun setCurrentPage(page: MyPageFragment) {
    _currentPage = WeakReference(page)
}
```

I decided to use `WeakReference`, so I don't leak inactive Fragment instances

And each of my fragments that I display inside `ViewPager2` inherits from common super class `MyPageFragment`. This class is responsible for registering its instance with host fragment in `onResume`:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    (parentFragment as HostFragment).setCurrentPage(this)
}
```

I also used this class to define common interface of paged fragments:

```
abstract fun someOperation1()

abstract fun someOperation2()
```

And then I can call them from the `HostFragment` like this:

```
currentPage?.someOperation1()
```

I'm not saying it's a nice solution, but I think it's more elegant than relying on internals of `ViewPager's` adapter with `instantiateItem` method that we had to use before.

Comment: Another really good answer is to override the onPageSelected function shown in this site https://proandroiddev.com/look-deep-into-viewpager2-13eb8e06e419

Comment: @BenAkin It's a really nice article, but I couldn't find there how to get the Fragment on current position, can you share it here?

Comment: @Micer you need to make a class like this class ViewPager2PageChangeCallback(private val listener: (Int) -> Unit) : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() { override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) { super.onPageSelected(position) Log.d(Util.DEBUG_LOG, "this currently is the postion: " + position) } }  then.... in the class/activity that uses the viewpager fragments, add this to the onCreate: mPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(viewPager2PageChangeCallback!!)

Comment: @BenAkin this callback gives you a `position: Int`, but you still don't have the `Fragment` object tho. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get access to current fragment in FragmentStateAdapter using **reflection**.

Extension function in Kotlin:

```
fun FragmentStateAdapter.getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
    return this::class.superclasses.find { it == FragmentStateAdapter::class }
        ?.java?.getDeclaredField("mFragments")
        ?.let { field ->
            field.isAccessible = true
            val mFragments = field.get(this) as LongSparseArray<Fragment>
            return@let mFragments[getItemId(position)]
        }
}
```

Add Kotlin reflection dependency if needed:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.61"
```

Example call:

```
val tabsAdapter = viewpager.adapter as FragmentStateAdapter
val currentFragment = tabsAdapter.getItem(viewpager.currentItem)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Added a note about Kotlin reflection dependency.

Comment: reflection is expensive have a look at my solution. @AndrazP

Answer (score 4):

```
supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("f" + viewpager.currentItem)
```

with `FragmentStateAdapter` in `placeFragmentInViewHolder(@NonNull final FragmentViewHolder holder)`add Fragment

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(fragment, "f" + holder.getItemId())
                    .setMaxLifecycle(fragment, STARTED)
                    .commitNow()
```

Comment: Could you please add a little information about **why** and **how** this line of code provides an answer to the question? Thanks...

Comment: When debugging I do see that the tag for added fragments is indeed "f0", "f1", etc but I wonder how reliable that is.

Comment: yes, how to use this snippet with fragment state adapter?

Comment: oh i figured it out! 

use something like this

mSomeButton.setOnClickListener(v -> { OneFragment oneFragment = (OneFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("f" + 0); if (oneFragment != null) oneFragment.setText("Hello");});

Answer (score 4):

May as well post my solution to this - it's the same basic approach as @Almighty 's, except I'm keeping the `Fragment` weak references in a lookup table in the `PagerAdapter`:

```
private class PagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle) {

    // only store as weak references, so you're not holding discarded fragments in memory
    private val fragmentCache = mutableMapOf<Int, WeakReference<Fragment>>()

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = tabList.size
    
    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        // return the cached fragment if there is one
        fragmentCache[position]?.get()?.let { return it }

        // no fragment found, time to make one - instantiate one however you
        // like and add it to the cache
        return tabList[position].fragment.newInstance()
            .also { fragmentCache[position] = WeakReference(it) }
            .also { Timber.d("Created a fragment! $it") }
    }

    // not necessary, but I think the code reads better if you
    // can use a getter when you want to... try to get an existing thing
    fun getFragment(position: Int) = createFragment(position)
}
```

and then you can call `getFragment` with the appropriate page number, like `adapter.currentPage` or whatever.

So basically, the adapter is keeping its own cache of fragments it's created, but with `WeakReference`s so it's not actually holding onto them, once the components actually using the fragments are done with them, they won't be in the cache anymore. So you can hold a lookup for all the current fragments.

---

You could have the getter just return the (nullable) result of the lookup, if you wanted. This version obviously creates the fragment if it doesn't already exist, which is useful if you expect it to be there. This can be handy if you're using `ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback`, which will fire with the new page number *before* the view pager creates the fragment - you can "get" the page, which will create and cache it, and when the pager calls `createFragment` it should still be in the cache and avoid recreating it.

**It's not guaranteed the weak reference won't have been garbage collected between those two moments though**, so if you're setting stuff on that fragment instance (rather than just reading something from it, like a title you want to display) be aware of that!

Comment: great solution!

Comment: doesnot work, createFragment is not called always because some kind of childFragmentManager or savedinstance states

Answer (score 4):

If you want the current `Fragment` to only perform some action in it, you can use a `SharedViewModel` which is shared between `ViewPager` container and its `Fragment`s and pass an `Identifier` to each fragment and observe to a `LiveData` in `SharedViewModel`. Set value of that `LiveData` to an object which consists of `Identifier` of the fragment you want to update (i.e. `Pair<String, MyData>` which `String` is type of the `Identifier`). Then inside your observers check if the current emitted `Identifer` is as same as the fragment's `Identifier` or not and consume data if it is equal.

 Its not as simple as using fragment's tags to find them, But it least you do not need to worry about changes to how `ViewPager2` create tag for each fragment.

Answer (score 3):

I simply use this in my tab fragment

```
fun currentFragment() = childFragmentManager.fragments.find { it.isResumed }
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to some other answers here, this is what I'm currently using.
I'm not clear on how reliable it is but at least one of these is bound to work .

```
//Unclear how reliable this is
fun getFragmentAtIndex(index: Int): Fragment? {
    return fm.findFragmentByTag("f${getItemId(index)}")
        ?: fm.findFragmentByTag("f$index")
        ?: fm.findFragmentById(getItemId(index).toInt())
        ?: fm.findFragmentById(index)
}
```

`fm` is the `supportFragmentManager`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I converted from ViewPager to ViewPager2, using FragmentStateAdapter. In my case I have a DetailActivity class (extends AppCompatActivity) which houses the ViewPager2, which is used to page through lists of data (Contacts, Media, etc.) on smaller form-factor devices.

I need to know the currently shown fragment (which is my own class DetailFragment which extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment), because that class contains the string I use to update the title on the DetailActivity toolbar.

I first started down the road of registering an onPageChangeCallback listener as suggested by some, but I quickly ran into problems:

1. I initially created tags during the ViewPager2's `adapter.createFragment()` call as suggested by some with the idea to add the newly created fragment to a Bundle object (using `FragmentManager.put()`) with that tag. This way I could then save them across config changes. The problem here is that during `createFragment()`, the fragment isn't actually yet part of the FragmentManager, so the put() calls fail.
2. The other problem is that if the fundamental idea is to use the onPageSelected() method of the OnPageChangeCallback to find the fragment using the internally generated "f"+position tag names - we again have the same timing issue: The very first time in, onPageSelected() is called PRIOR to the `createFragment()` call on the adapter - so there are no fragments yet created and added to the FragmentManager, so I can't get a reference to that first fragment using the "f0" tag.
3. I then tried to find a way where I could save the position passed in to onPageSelected, then try and reference that somewhere else in order to retrieve the fragment after the adapter had made the `createFragment()` calls - but I could not identify any type of handler within the adapter, the associated recyclerview, the viewpager etc. that allows me to surface the list of fragments that I could then reference that to the position identified within that listener. Strangely, for example, one adapter method that looked very promising was `onViewAttachedToWindow()` - however it is marked final so can't be overridden (even though the JavaDoc clearly anticipates it being used this way).

So what I ended up doing that worked for me was the following:

1. In my DetailFragment class, I created an interface that can be implemented by the hosting activity:

```
    public interface DetailFragmentShownListener {
        // Allows classes that extend this to update visual items after shown
        void onDetailFragmentShown(DetailFragment me);
    }
```

2. Then I added code within onResume() of DetailFragment to see if the associated activity has implemented the DetailFragmentShownListener interface within this class, and if so I make the callback:

```
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        View v = getView();
        if (v!=null && v.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
            v.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    // Let our parent know we are laid out
                    if ( getActivity() instanceof DetailFragmentShownListener ) {
                        ((DetailFragmentShownListener) getActivity()).onDetailFragmentShown(DetailFragment.this);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

2. Then where I need to know when this fragment is shown (such as within  DetailActivity), I implement the interface and when it receives this callback I know that this is the current fragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onDetailFragmentShown(DetailFragment me) {
        mCurrentFragment = me;
        updateToolbarTitle();
    }
```

`mCurrentFragment` is a property of this class as its used in various other places.

Answer (score 1):

The ViewPagerAdapter is intended to hide all these implementation details which is why there is no straight-forward way to do it.

You could try setting and id or tag on the fragment when you instantiate it in `getItem()` then use `fragmentManager.findFragmentById()` or `fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()` to retrieve.

Doing it like this, however, is a bit of a code smell. It suggests to me that stuff is being done in the activity when it should be done in the fragment (or elsewhere).

Perhaps there is another approach to achieve what you want but it's hard to give suggestions without knowing why you need to get the current fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for get fragment by position:

```
class ClubPhotoAdapter(
    private val dataList: List<MyData>,
    fm: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle) {

    private val fragmentMap = mutableMapOf<Int, WeakReference<MyFragment>>()

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataList.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        val fragment = MyFragment[dataList.getOrNull(position)]

        fragmentMap[position] = WeakReference(fragment)

        return fragment
    }

    fun getItem(position: Int): MyFragment? = fragmentMap[position]?.get()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solutions with WeakReference did not worked for me because Android restores the state and `createFragment` is not always called, so I was always getting nulls.

Here is my try and seems to be woking fine:

```kotlin
val fragment = childFragmentManager.fragments.first {
    it.lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED
}
```

this will iterate over the fragments and return one which is RESUMED, meaning it will be the current selected fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current fragment from `ViewPager2` like following,

```
adapter.getRegisteredFragment(POSITION);
```

Sample `FragmentStateAdapter`,

```
public class ViewPagerAdapterV2 extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    private final FragmentActivity context;
    private final HashMap<Integer, Fragment> mapFragments;

    public ViewPagerAdapterV2(FragmentActivity fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = fm;
        this.mapFragments = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return NUMBER_OF_PAGES;
    }

    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        return mapFragments.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {    
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        mapFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a bad idea because then you are storing the fragment, while the ViewPager may be recycling it (destroying and recreating as needed).

Comment: @JeffPadgett exactly, this implementation causes memory leak issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found this works for me even after the activity gets destroyed and re-created.
The key can be any type. Assume you have ViewModel used for your fragment.

```
fun findFragment(fragmentId: String?): YourFragment? {
    fragmentId?: return null
    return supportFragmentManager.fragments.filterIsInstance(YourFragment::class.java).find { it.viewModel.yourData.value.id == fragmentId}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid finding fragment with the hard-coded tag `f$id` [set internally](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/viewpager2/viewpager2/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter.java#351) which might be changed by Google in any future release:

**Method 1: filtering the page fragments with the resumed one**

Assuming the page fragment of the `ViewPager2` is `PageFragment`, then you can find the current `ViewPager` fragment in the current fragmentManager `fragments` and check if it is in the resumed state (currently displayed on the screen)

```
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments
                            .find{ it is PageFragment && it.isResumed } as PageFragment
```

Note: `supportFragmentManager` should be replaced with `childFragmentManager` if the `ViewPager` is a part of a Fragment.

**For java (API 24+):**

```
Fragment fragment =
        getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().stream()
                .filter(it -> it instanceof PageFragment && it.isResumed())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().findFirst().get();
```

**Method 2: setting some argument to the PageFragment, and filter fragments based on it**

Kotlin:

Adapter

```
class MyAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

    //.... omitted

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment 
                = PageFragment.getInstance(position)

}
```

PageFragment:

```
class PageFragment : Fragment() {

    //.... omitted

    companion object {
        const val POSITION = "POSITION";
        fun getInstance(position: Int): PageFragment {
            return PageFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().also {
                    it.putInt(POSITION, position)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And filter with the position argument to get the needed PageFragment:

```
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments.firstOrNull { 
             it is PageFragment && it.arguments?.getInt("POSITION") == id }  // id from the viewpager >> for instance `viewPager.currentItem`
```

Java (API 24+):

Adapter:

```
class MyAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    
    // .... omitted

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return PagerFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

}
```

PageFragment:

```
public class PagerFragment extends Fragment {

    // .... omitted

    public static Fragment newInstance(int position) {
        PagerFragment fragment = new PagerFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("POSITION", position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

And to get a fragment of a certain `viewPager` item:

```
Optional<Fragment> optionalFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(it -> it instanceof PagerFragment && it.getArguments() != null && it.getArguments().getInt("POSITION") == id)
                    .findFirst();

optionalFragment.ifPresent(fragment -> {
    // This is your needed PageFragment
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to rely on tags. **ViewPager2** hides implementation details, but we all know it has an inner recycler so the layout manager would do the trick. We can write something like this:

```
fun ViewPager2.getCurrentView(): View? {
    return (getChildAt(0) as RecyclerView).layoutManager?.getChildAt(currentItem)
}

fun ViewPager2.getCurrentFragment(): Fragment? {
    return getCurrentView().findFragment()
}
```

It would also works for for any given position not only the first one if you want to.

Comment: this returns a `View` and not a `Fragment`

Comment: @JahirFiquitiva there is an SDK extension on Views named `findFragment()` you can use on retrieved views. I've updated my response to cover it.

Answer (score -2):

was facing same issue now its solved by adding one object in adapter

```
class MyViewPager2Adapter(fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {


    private val FRAGMENTS_SIZE = 2

    var currentFragmentWeakReference: WeakReference<Fragment>? = null

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return this.FRAGMENTS_SIZE
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {

        when (position) {
            0 -> {
                currentFragmentWeakReference= MyFirstFragment()
                return MyFirstFragment()
            }
            1 -> {
                currentFragmentWeakReference= MySecondFragment()
                return MySecondFragment()
            }
        }

        return MyFirstFragment() /for default view

    }

}
```

after creating adapter I registered my Viewpager 2 with  `ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback()`
and overrided its method `onPageSelected`

now simple did this trick to get current fragment

```
 private fun getCurrentFragment() :Fragment?{

        val fragment = (binding!!.pager.adapter as MyViewPager2Adapter).currentFragmentWeakReference?.get()

        retrun fragment
    }
```

> I've only tested this with 2 fragments in ViewPager2

cheers guys , hope this mayhelp you.!

Comment: This solution doesn't handle process configuration changes (i.e. phone kills app in background) - `createFragment` is not called when that happens as it just restores the previous fragment staet. Your weakReference will be null.

Comment: then you will leak