# How to get Current Fragment in ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager2

i used this ViewPager2 dependency:

implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'

then i wrote code and make Adapter for FragmentStateAdapter like below:

```
private inner class ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
                                         lifecycle: Lifecycle, config: TribunConfig?)
        : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {
        private val config: TribunConfig?
        override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
            return TribunNewsFragment.newInstance(if (menuTribun!!.get(position) == "News") "home"
            else menuTribun!!.get(position)!!.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase(), config)!!
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return menuTribun!!.size
        }

        init {
            this.config = config
        }
    }
```

an in method `onCreate` i implement some code related viewpager2 and its adapter like below:

```
        viewPager2!!.offscreenPageLimit = 1
        viewPager2!!.adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle, config)
        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout!!, viewPager2!!, TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy { tab: TabLayout.Tab?, position: Int -> tab!!.text = menuTribun!!.get(position) }).attach()
```

But i have problem when i want to make swipeRefresh. My swipeRefresh needs current fragment to access the method inside fragment. But there is **NO METHOD** `getItem` in FragmentStateAdapter. Anyone can help me?

Comment: 1. Create property in your adapter to save all your fragments 2. Save current position 3. Get fragment from frgament list (property) by position when you need it

Comment: can you show in code please. so i can vote your answer, if it's correct

Comment: Are you familiar with EventBus?

Comment: @dariushf no, not yet

Comment: @NandaZ : Please show your code how you add fragment in viewpager

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan did you mean that you want to see `TribunNewsFragment` class? if you want to know how i added fragment, i have wrote it in method `createFragment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create property in your adapter to save all your fragments
2. Save current position
3. Get fragment from fragment list (property) by position when you need it

Something like this:

```
    val fragments: MutableList<Fragment> = mutableListOf()

    private val config: TribunConfig?
    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        val fragment = TribunNewsFragment.newInstance(if (menuTribun!!.get(position) == "News") "home"
        else menuTribun!!.get(position)!!.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase(), config)!!

        fragments.add(fragment)
        return fragment
    }
```

Parent:

```
 yourTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            val fragment = adapter.fragments[tab!!.position]
            // cast fragment to your fragment class and do what you want
        }

        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        }

        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        }
    })
```

Also you can use `when` or `if-else` for your fragments position or create base class with methods you need and cast getting fragment to it.

Comment: As a note ViewPager2 has a page changed callback https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback so this could be done without Tabs

Comment: But, i had counter problem. When i try to click tab which the index is more than size of mutableList and it cause crash

Comment: How is it possible? Do you have more tabs than fragments?

Comment: it's because of `viewPager2!!.offscreenPageLimit = 1`, so i don't create all fragment just two fragment for first opening

Comment: So it's easy. CurrentTab.position+1 is maximum for you, except lastPosition.

Comment: I think i can accept your answer, because i add delay time for event in `onTabSelected`. It's works now

Comment: This doesn't handle configuration changes (i.e. app running out of memory in the background) - `createFragment` is not called when that happens, it is restored without calling that and your list becomes empty.

Comment: @Iawonga is right. You need to store the fragments in a `FragmentManager` and retrieve them after the config change using `putFragment` and `getFragment` respectively. This is obviously a lot of boilerplate and I think the more formal answer is to avoid relying on fragment references in your activity if possible. I've yet to see a good example by google on how to handle this.

Comment: An alternative would be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61178226/4322363) that relies on the internal logic of `ViewPager2` storing fragments by tag.

Comment: This causes memory leak issues for the fragments maintained in mutablelist.

Comment: I store the fragment on the Tabs, that can be retrievable for non-static (the ListSectionFragment class is static, and in it it refuses non-static access). But by storing static MainActivity mainActivity = null; I can reach the TabLayout.Tab tTab = mainActivity.tabLayout.getTabAt(iTab); and do tTab.setTag(fragment) and get it by tTab.getTag(). Question is if it is a good practice to store the MainActivity in itself and update it onCreate() and onResume()? It looks to be working. I don't like lists of what is in the running application, I love tagging the resources to each other, a better way.

Comment: The Tab-tags are updated with the new fragments created ListSectionFragment class 
onCreateView dynamically, and I do not have to keep track of what is there and what is wasted. Also It is possible to read the previous fragment variables and put their values into the new fragment, being able to store things like zoom factor in each fragment etc. I find it smooth. Question is if it is a good practice to store the MainActivity in itself, looks to work well. Looks to be working with multiple instances (one from storage and one from email), no problem. Jumping between resets the sessions however.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Oleg's answer, you can access the Fragments like this in your Adapter instead of creating a local list and adding each fragment on `createFragment` method:

```
private val fragmentList: List<TribunNewsFragment>
        get() {
            return fragment.childFragmentManager.fragments.filterIsInstance<TribunNewsFragment>()
        }
```

It's important to use `childFragmentManager` instead of `fragmentManager` if you are creating the ViewPager inside another fragment.

And it survives configuration changes, regarding @lawonga's comment on the answer's topic.

Comment: It looks like you already have a `fragment` reference here. How are you referencing it from your adapter?