# Get current fragment in viewpager2 in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Before I migrate to viewPager2, I get current fragment at this way to use methods inside it:

```
Fragment myFragment = (Fragment) viewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

But, now I get an error on **instantiateItem**:

> Cannot resolve method 'instantiateItem(androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2, int)'

I don't use Tag to create Fragments in ViewPager Adapter:

```
    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return ScreenFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

So, How I can get the current fragment in viewPager2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HashMap to do this:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Fragment> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
     Fragment fragment = ScreenFragment.newInstance(position);
     hashMap.put(position, fragment);
     return fragment;
}
```

And then get current fragment at this way:

```
ScreenFragment screenFragment = (ScreenFragment) hashMap.get(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This doesn't handle config changes. Might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62056804/4625681) answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect and easy solution by @Zain.

just want to add a little more:

You have to call childFragmentManager through your activity fragment manager instance.

```
SupportFragmentManager.Fragments[0].ChildFragmentManager.Fragments[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an easier way with ViewPager2 is to do something like

`childFragmentManager.fragments[viewPager.currentItem - 1]`

This will give you access to the current fragment.