# Update whole ViewPager2 fragment contents

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a ViewPager2 with TabLayout in a host fragment.

This ViewPager2 is also hosting several other fragments which contains a RecyclerView (A list).

```
Host_Fragment
   -> ViewPager2 (FragmentStateAdapter)
      -> Fragment1
         - RV + Adapter
      -> Fragment2
         - RV + Adapter
      -> Fragment3
         - RV + Adapter
```

My goal is I want to update the data in the list in RecyclerView. It's kinda hard for me to traverse back to the individual RecyclerView adapter to update it, so I decided to refresh the top level ViewPager2 fragments instead.

Unfortunately, after I send back the new data in the ViewPager2 adapter and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, it's not working.

My `FragmentStateAdapter` look like this:

```kotlin
class ProductAdapter(
    fragment: Fragment,
    private val products: List<Data>
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

    private var mutableList = products.toMutableList()

    override fun getItemCount() = products.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return ProductsFragment(mutableList[position].products) 
    }

    // here i want to update the contents of this ViewPager2 with new set of data
    fun updateItem(updatedData: List<Data>) {
        mutableList.clear()
        mutableList.addAll(updatedData)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

And I want to supply the new set of data like this:

```kotlin
// do modification to listProducts
adapter.updateItem(listProducts)
```

From Host Fragment, ViewPager2 adapter is set up like this:

```kotlin
adapter = ProductAdapter(
    fragment = this@HostFragment,
    products = listProducts
)
viewPager.adapter = adapter
```

How do I refresh the ViewPager2 fragments, so that it refreshes the whole RecyclerView with new data?

Answer (score 1):

Notifying `PagerAdapter`  is not gonna work for this .. You can do this in several way .

1. Set new Adapter to `ViewPager2` .
2. You can get have a `WeakReference` Fragment list inside your `ProductAdapter` . this way you can access each fragment and call any method of these fragment to update the data . you can also get the fragment [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55728719/get-current-fragment-with-viewpager2) ..
3. Have a shared `ViewModel` with Owner being the fragment which has the `ViewPager2` in it i.e Your `HostFragment`. This way you can listen for the changes in the `products` list with an Observable like `LiveData` and take action on it . IMO this one is better way to do this .

Comment: Thanks for your input. For number 3, where do I put the receiver observable? Is it in the Adapter or the individual tabbed fragments?

Comment: In `ProductFragment` Do not put anything in adapter .. keep it clean ..

Comment: I see, okay. But, how do I know to which `ProductFragment` it has to update? Since I'm using a ViewPager which has multiple fragments inside it.